# Which class class is org.apache.lucene.document.IntPoint$1?

Tags: lucene, range-query

I was coded the following lines for other purpose, when I observed a weird thing. The class of q is class org.apache.lucene.document.IntPoint$1, but I really can't find it in the doc.

```
Query q = IntPoint.newExactQuery("year", 2147483647);
System.out.println(q.getClass()); # this line prints out "class org.apache.lucene.document.IntPoint$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous class defined within newRangeQuery (because newExactQuery is implemented using it) on line 199 of [IntPoint.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/document/IntPoint.java).